# Watir: How to wait until a div is no longer visible

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am running some BDD tests with Cucumber, Watir and the Selenium Driver. One of the tests I need to run is to ensure that a loading div disappears once the page is loaded, and then that a search box appears.

I have this line : 
`@browser.text_field(placeholder: /Search/).wait_until(&:present?)`
which should wait until the search box is visible, but it doesn't.
I want to then `wait_until` the `div id='loader'` is *not* visbile.

I don't know how to express this with Watir.

Comment: Can you write some text into text box and check whether it's writing text into that corresponding text filed.

Comment: @Rajagopalan yes that is the strange thing. I can set text in the box... However when I try to click on the updated div it gets an error stating that the link is not clickable because it is obscured by another div: the one which is still loading

Comment: If another div is obscuring it, then wait for that element to disappear first and then stimulate the click to the desired element.

Comment: @Rajagopalan yes that's exactly what I want to do, but I don't know how to express that with watit

Comment: Are you excuting in Firefox or Chrome? If you are exciting in Firefox then I know the way to solve this by some other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Waiting for something to disappear can be done by using `#wait_while`:

```
browser.div(id: 'loader').wait_while(&:present?)
```